# Examples of symmetry-breaking solitons which retain a subgroup symmetry

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, schrodinger-operators

There are many works on spontaneous symmetry breaking in the Nonlinear Schrödinger equation with asymmetric soliton solutions.

However, all symmetry breaking soliton examples I have seen go from the original symmetry group to the trivial group.

Can anyone point me to explicit examples of symmetry-breaking groundstate solitons which retain a non-trivial subgroup symmetry?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It might help if you briefly exhibited one of these examples you've seen, to give people some guidance on what you're looking for. Otherwise, the question will remain nebulous to a significant number of people who in principle might be able to contribute.